# Would it be possible to power a small micro controller and an RGB LED using a size 675 Zinc Air battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-operated

I'm wondering if it would be possible to power a small micro controller and an LED using just one size 675 Zinc Air battery? The idea is to use a boost converter to step up the voltage.

I know zinc air batteries have a high self discharge rate. But for the application I'm thinking of I would like the most amount of battery life for a 3 to 4 week period so Zinc Air still seems like a great solution.

Any insight would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What does the datasheet for the battery say?

Comment: I use those things (almost) on a daily basis. I can't recall any of them lasting 3-4 weeks, just on self-discharge alone. If I expose them (lift the tab off) then I get maybe a week. I would expect them to be completely dead in a month just sitting around on a shelf. Definitely check the datasheet. But... I don't have a lot of hope.

Comment: Why waste precious power stepping up the voltage? You can get microcontrollers that will run from 1.45V

Answer (score 0):

Zinc air current is typically limited, but as long as you picked a microcontroller with a low enough current requirement, and picked a battery model that could supply that current, it could be done.  The LED will not be very bright.